# What is the use of Zookeeper?

Tags: apache-kafka

If we define the Kafka server as a property in ***application.properties*** file **like:**

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
```

Then what is the use of zookeeper to maintain the cluster of brokers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Elects a controller between all brokers**. This is the machine that will tell others who is leader/follower for each partition. Zookeeper takes the decission of choosing the controller and delegates on him that task.
2. He is the "**Topic Administrator**". He knows the number of topics, their names, their configs, preferred leaders, and so on. He is the one you call, for example, to change the retention time of a topic.
3. Controls **cluster membership**. Monitors which brokers are alive and which cluster they belong to.
4. **ACLs** on topic level (zookeeper znodes).

It might be used as well for other things, as quotas (even if I am not sure this is still true in recent versions) and surely a lot of other hidden synchronization stuff going on. 
But generally speaking, that should be, more or less, the actual role of zookeeper.

Comment: According to your answer Zookeeper will decide which Kafka Broker process our request, but my concern is that if i am defining a particular Broker address in my properties file (ex:198.2.1.2:9092) then how will zookeeper send the request to another broker.

Comment: No, I didn't say zookeeper chooses who processes your request. Zookeeper elects a controller, that is, a BROKER, who is the one who decides which broker takes your request. That's why you only need to pass the broker connection, as your client will not talk to zookeeper. Depending on the partition you are attacking, a different broker will process the request (as all partitions have at least a leader and 0 to n followers, depending on replication)

Comment: ok, i dont know whether i understand correctly or not!!!.  But if i said there are two brokers one is running at b1:9092 and another one on b2:9092, both forming a cluster and connected to zookeeper running on z:2181.  Now if i define broker b1:9092 in my properties file and tried to get a message that is available on b2:9092. Will it work?

Comment: Yes, it will work like a charm. Connecting a client to a broker connects it to the entire cluster.

Comment: the brokers param you list is just used to query for metadata about the entire cluster. Once the rest of the cluster is dynamically discovered connections are made to all the brokers in the cluster that contain partitions your app is using. This is what allows Kafka to scale horizontally using parallel processing and partitions spread across the cluster. For fault tolerance you should list two or three brokers in your broker list just in case the first one is down and unable to return the cluster metadata to your app when it starts